# How does database views keep the fast query speed when multiple FK-PK relationships among all the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, rdbms

These days I've faced performance issues when binding data with Java object to database. Especially when paring the data from database to java code when a lot of FK-PK relationship involved. I realized the issue and solved the performance slowdown by creating database views and create POJOs to map with the view.

I did some research online but couldn't find a good answer for this: How does database(I am using mysql) keeps the fast data querying speed in views?

For example, if I create a view among 10 tables, with FK-PK relationship, the view is still pretty fast to query and display the result pretty fast. How exactly happened behind the scenes for the database engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes.

[MySQL implicitly creates a foreign key index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) (i.e. an index on columns that compose the foreign key), unless one already exists. Not all database engines do so.

A view is little more than an aliased query. As such, any view, as trivial as it may seem, could kill the server if written poorly. Execution time is not proportional with the number of joined tables, but with the quality of indexes<sup>*</sup>.

Side effect: the default index might not be the most efficient one.

---

<sup>*</sup>*tables sizes also start to matter when the tables grow large, as in millions of records*